# Почему inline кнопка не работает

Tags: python, telebot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Возникает данная проблема: не получается перейти в другую функцию по поводу inline кнопки: выполнение кода остается в той же функции.

```
 import telebot
 from telebot import types

 token = ''
 bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
 a = 0
 b = 0
 @bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
   markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
   k1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Продолжить', callback_data = 'load_test')
   markup.add(k1)
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет. Нажми кнопку продолжить', reply_markup = markup, parse_mode='HTML')
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def ans1(call):
    if call.data == 'load_test':
    global markup
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    k1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = '1)', callback_data = 'one')
    k2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = '2)', callback_data = 'two')
    k3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = '3)', callback_data = 'three')
    k4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = '4)', callback_data = 'four')
    markup.add(k1, k2, k3, k4)
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,  
    message_id=call.message.message_id, reply_markup = None)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Какую ты цифру нажмешь?', reply_markup = markup, parse_mode='HTML')
def ans2(call):
if call.data == 'three':
    global a
    a + 1
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    k1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = '1)', callback_data = '1')
    k2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = '2)', callback_data = '2')
    k3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = '3)', callback_data = '3')
    k4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = '4)', callback_data = '4')
    markup.add(k1, k2, k3, k4)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ты нажал цифру 3.")[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,  message_id=call.message.message_id, reply_markup = None)
```

Comment: А где декоратор у функции ans2?

Comment: А зачем он? Я пробовал, все равно не работает

Comment: Декоратор callback_query_handler нужен чтобы обрабатывать нажатие inline кнопки, например: @bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: call.data == “three”) def ans2(call): global a… и внутри функции условие тогда тоже не нужно

Comment: Все, я понял, спасибо. Я декоратор вставлял такой же, какой и первый.